# AWS S3 browser upload integrity check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does AWS S3 perform an integrity check (via a checksum) on uploads performed using the browser? There is clear documentation regarding this for the CLI tool but none for when uploading via the browser.

Comment: CLI, browser or other clients all using the same AWS API

Comment: @MichelFeldheim that's almost true but not quite.  Form-based `POST` uploads use a different action and different semantics from everything else, and this is a very good question.